# How to concatenate two model fields in a Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, concatenation, django-queryset, django-annotate

Consider a table called `DataTable`. It has two fields: `A` and `B`.

I want to return all rows from this table, and annotating a field called `C` which is a concatenation of `A` and `B` fields.

Here is what I have tried:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from .models import DataTable

def Test(request):
    query = DataTable.objects.all().annotate(C=Value('A' + '-' + 'B', 
          output_field=CharField()))
    # the rest of the function...
```

The problem here is that `C` is literally just the string literal "A - B" for every returned row.

I want to concatenate the values of `A` and `B` fields.

Comment: did you use `F()`? F('A')

Answer (score 31, accepted):

looks like you need [concat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat):

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

query = DataTable.objects.annotate(C=Concat('A', 
          Value('-'), 'B', output_field=CharField()))
```

Comment: Perfect...now how do add a hyphen in between A and B

Comment: Since you can't use a `CONCAT` function in an index because its behavior changes based on settings, how would you concat in Django using the `||` operator?

Answer (score 12):

Basically there are two approaches to achieve it.

**First one:**
First of all, you need to import the following expressions.

```
from django.db.models import F, Value, Func
```

then, concatenate the fields as below:

```
ann_concat = Customer.objects.annotate(
            fullName = Func(F('first_name'), Value(' '),F('last_name'), function= 'CONCAT'))
```

In above example, I have concatenated first name and last name into a new field called fullName.

**Second one:**
This approach is way shorter than the first one you only need to import  Concat() and Value() for making the spaces functions.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat


  short_syntax = Customer.objects.annotate(full_name = Concat('first_name',Value(' '),'last_name'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with `Value()` and of course `Concat` django

`Value` is to set the white space or `-`, try the following:

```
from django.db.models import Value, CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Concat


def Test(request):
     query = DataTable.objects.annotate(C=Concat('A',Value('-') ,'B',
                 output_field=CharField())
      # the rest of the function...
```

Comment: `F` not need for `Concat` )

Comment: perfect, added in Value(' - ') instead of Value(' ').

Comment: @Lemayzeur glad to help you